# Multiple calls to configure website not working

Tags: .htaccess

Trying to get these two to work together. I've tried a few different ways of constructing the code but have had no luck. I'm unsure as to what I've done wrong, even though the answer may seem basic.

Trying to redirect to SSL and remove .html

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC, L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to literally *mash* the rules together. These are two separate rules and should remain entirely separate. `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` that follows. But neither do you want to exclude directories and `.html` file requests from the HTTP to HTTPS redirect.

The condition that checks for the existence of `.html` files is not strictly correct. Depending on the requested URL, this could result in a rewrite loop, since you are not testing the same thing that you are ultimately rewriting to. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following ServerFault question that goes into more detail on this:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Try the following instead (in your root `.htaccess` file):

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
```

Additional notes:

- No need for the directory filesystem check, unless you have directories that also end in `.html`.
- The regex `(.*)` is the same as `^(.*)$` since regex is greedy by default.
- No need to backslash escape the literal dot in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* since this is not a regex and the dot carries no special meaning here. ie. `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html` - the backslash is superfluous here.
- You had an erroneous space in the `RewriteRule` *flags* ie. `[NC, L]` - this would have resulted in a 500 error response ("invalid flags"). It should be `[NC,L]`.
- The `NC` flag on the `RewriteRule` is superfluous, since you are matching everything anyway.

*Aside:*

> ... and remove .html

Whilst the ultimate goal is to "remove `.html`" - these directives specifically add it back (they don't "remove" anything). The `.html` extension has presumably already been removed in your HTML source.